# missing Parenthesis in call to print, while installing Apriori

Tags: python

while writing this code

```
transactions = [a[1]['itemDescription'].tolist() for a in list(cust_level.groupby(["Member_number"]))]
#Import Apriori
from apriori import apriori
rules = apriori(transactions = transactions, min_support = 0.002, min_Confidence = 0.05, min_lift = 3, min_length = 2)
results = list(rules)
results
```

I am getting this error:

```
<ipython-input-81-dc647f33b0b3>:1: FutureWarning: In a future version of pandas, a length 1 tuple will be returned when iterating over a groupby with a grouper equal to a list of length 1. Don't supply a list with a single grouper to avoid this warning.
  transactions = [a[1]['itemDescription'].tolist() for a in list(cust_level.groupby(["Member_number"]))]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3553, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-81-dc647f33b0b3>", line 3, in <cell line: 3>
from apriori import apriori

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/apriori.py", line 79
    print freqSet-conseq,'-->',conseq,'conf:',conf
    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?
```

I was trying to import Apriori in my code and encountered this error

Comment: Doesn't look like apriori.py is Python3 compatible.

Comment: Which `apriori` exactly? [This one from 2013](https://pypi.org/project/apriori/), I'm guessing; but there are [many more to choose from](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html?q=pypi%20apriori), at least some of which seem to have been updated more recently. Python 2 finally was end-of-lifed in 2020; you really want a Python 3 solution.

Comment: Or if you are really desperate to use exactly that version only, see if `2to3` can translate it for you.